# How to assign label to nodes part of docker swarm cluster using Ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-swarm

I have a 3 node docker cluster(swarm) and want the nodes to be assigned labels. The node I'm presently ssh'ed to is node 1 and should be assigned the label abc1. The other 2 nodes should be assigned abc2 and abc3.

I have tried the examples given in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/docker_node_module.html but seem to get YAML Syntax error.

My Yaml:

```
  - name: Assigning labels
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: false

    tasks:
      - name: Localhost label assignment
        docker_node:
          hostname: vm-test
          label:
            abc1: true
```

Error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    tasks:
      - name: Localhost label assignment
        ^ here
```

With what I have, it will assign the label to only the node 1. How do I assign the incremental labels to node 2 and node 3 to abc2 and abc3 respectively?

The hosts file looks like:

```
[target-machines]
10.xx.xx.xx ansible_sudo_pass=xyz ansible_ssh_pass=xyz ansible_ssh_user=xyz
10.xx.xx.xx ansible_sudo_pass=abc ansible_ssh_pass=abc ansible_ssh_user=abc
```

Is there a way I can loop over the hosts file and assign the labels?

Comment: You yaml is correct, your module parameters hash is not. As described on the documentation linked in your question, you want to use the parameter label**s**

Answer (score 3):

This module is introduced in `ansible 2.8`.  Upgrade your Ansible to 2.8 and error will go away.
 `pip install ansible==2.8.0rc1`

The parameter hash is `labels` not label.

```
---
- name: Assigning labels
  hosts : localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: Merge node labels and new labels
      docker_node:
        hostname: vm-test
        labels:
          abc1: true
```

Comment: Thanks much @SaGePpidy.
How do I perform the labels assignment for the other set of nodes, that was the second part of my question. For me to accept the answer can you help me on that front as well?